# Replace will_paginate links after ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, will-paginate

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails aplicattion, my problem is that I have all the comments of a post paginated and showed perfectly, but when an user saves a new comment via ajax, and I replace all the content with the partial with the new content(including the will_paginate @comments), the urls of the links change to the url of the action that saves the comments and i don't know how to do to make them link correctly.

I tried with `<%= will_paginate @comments, :params => {:controller => 'posts', :action => 'show_outside_comments' %>`
But I get the same results.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the ajax methods described here?

http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax

Comment: Yes, but I don't need to paginate with ajax, I only need to replace the html that contains the pagination links (linking to the url that I want).

Answer (score 0):

you can execute javascript code to update the links,
something like:

```
<div class="paging_links" >
<%= will_paginate @comments, :params => {:controller => 'posts', :action => 'show_outside_comments' %>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery('.paging_links a').click(function(event){
        href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        event.preventDefault();
        // update href here
      })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.pagination a').attr('href', function() { 
  $(this).prop('href').replace('/comments', location.pathname); 
});
```

Assuming you want to replace `/comments' with the current pathname.